# inserting default value along with other columns

Tags: mysql

Hi help in this case i need to insert two columns in a table one column has to be default value as 'Other'(Please don't suggest to put Other as default value) and other column should get inserted from different table. 
This is my sample code please suggest necessary change:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (`ID`,`specialty`) 
SELECT `ID`,`here i need to put default value as other` from table2 a WHERE
Id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID,specialty) 
SELECT ID, 'Other'
FROM table2
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
```